# WinPE3 with Teamviewer over LAN - doesn´t connect

Tags: windows, dll, recovery, winpe, teamviewer

for a remote backup and recovery solution, I want to create a WinPE Environment with embedded Teamviewer (newest possible version)

Now I found a tutorial which describes this steps. (unfortunately its not english so its just for information)

http://www.andysblog.de/windows-teamviewer-und-winpe-eine-boot-cd-fuer-den-remote-support

You have to mount the WIM Image, copy few DLLs into the System32 Folder

> c:\windows\system32\avicap32.dll
>
> c:\windows\system32\msvfw32.dll
>
> c:\windows\system32\de-de\avicap32.dll.mui
>
> c:\windows\system32\de-de\msvfw32.dll.mui

and use the Teamviewer Quicksupport Ver. 5 (Portable Version works too)
which is important because all versions above 5 doesn´t work in the WinPE environment.

I did everything as decribed (in a VM machine), and tried to connect over LAN (without ID - not over the Teamviewer server) - My Teamviewer 10 didn´t connect and gave the following error: "Protocol negotiation failed"

Any suggestions?

The second problem is, that I would like to run the newest possible version, according to some reports, Teamviewer above Ver 5 checks in which account it runs. - If it is the SYSTEM account it will try to switch the account, if it fails it closes without any error message.

So I need also a solution for this. Maybe how to run programs in WinPE as different user and not as the default SYSTEM account.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I figured it out.

You have to run the full install in WinPE and check the "run-on-startup-feature" which registers it as a service. Now I was able to connect without any problems.

Though it does not have any sense to "install" Teamviewer everytime I boot the WinPE environment, so I did all the settings I need and exported them to a *.reg File on a USB drive.
Also copied the new installed Teamviewer folder to include it in the WIM Image later, and will create a batch file which loads the *.reg File on every boot and then starts up "Teamwiever" - Let´s see if this works.

Comment: what teamviewer version you able to make it run in WinPE? can share some install details?